# Read a value from JSON array in Node .js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I need to access the "State" value from the following array --

```
data =   
{ 
    Images:
    [ 
        {
            ProductCodes: [],
            BlockDeviceMappings: [Object],
            Tags: [],
            ImageId: 'ami-75301c',
            ImageLocation: '54696560/Test Image 3',
            State: 'available',       
            VirtualizationType: 'pavirtul',
            Hypervisor: 'xen' 
        }
    ],
    requestId: '2eb809d3-7f82-4142-b5d1-6af3' 
}
```

When I try `data.Images["State"]` or `data.Images.State` I get undefined.

Thanks

Comment: Good, that means everything is working properly. Your Array referenced by `Images` has no `State` property. If you indent your structure cleanly, things may become clear.

Comment: How do I access the State value? I need'available'back.

Comment: Well, `Images` is referencing an Array, and an Array is an ordered collection of data accessible via 0-based indices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images maps to an array which stores objects, so you have to specify the index of the item you want. Try data.images[0]["State"].

Comment: You should probably check if there are any array elements prior to getting the state item inside that array.  An array *could* be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can access like this:

```
data.Images[0].State
```

Or even:

```
data.Images[0]['State']
```

Answer (score -1):

Access the state with `data.image[0].state`. Your method was wrong because inside the `image`, you need an index within the two square bracket, the image property is an array.