# How to read nest array elements from mongoose schema using nodesjs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

Her is my mongoose schema code for Users:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
 
  Addtasks : [{
    website: String,
    otherdetails: String,
    exampleRadios: String,
    deadline: Date,
    Date: String,
    fileName: String,
    Bigpaths:[]
  }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And this is mongodb data stored in jSON format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f378bec5bd30f3248ffae59"),
    "email" : "vikasthapar95@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Vikas Yadav",
    "Addtasks" : [ 
        {
            "website" : "grumpytext.com",
            "keywords" : "article importance, article generation, article quality",
            "words" : 1234567,
            "topic" : "How article is generated?",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f379c7164a77a338483704c"),
            "Bigpaths" : [ 
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml",
                    "name" : "chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml"
                }, 
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\chrome_proxy.exe",
                    "name" : "chrome_proxy.exe"
                }, 
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\master_preferences",
                    "name" : "master_preferences"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Now what I want is that to iterate the Bigpaths nested array only which is inside Addtasks array and get the data from it for every object of its through loop. How can I achieve that? I have tried kind of populate() thing but seems doesnt help. Please help!!

Desired Result:

```
[
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml",
                }, 
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\chrome_proxy.exe",
                }, 
                {
                    "path" : "public\\files\\master_preferences",
                }

]
```

Expected Result on UI side (handlebar):

```
Path 1 = public\\files\\chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml
Path 2 = public\\files\\chrome_proxy.exe
Path 3 = public\\files\\master_preferences
```

Comment: can you add expected result in your question

Comment: Updated the expected result. @turivisal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will combine all documents path in root,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `Addtasks` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Addtasks.Bigpaths` array
- `$replaceRoot` will replace `path: Addtasks.Bigpaths.path` in new root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$Addtasks" },
  { $unwind: "$Addtasks.Bigpaths" },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { path: "$Addtasks.Bigpaths.path" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/foorm99ebjH)

---

for accessing items from your document,

```
let paths = [];
data.Addtasks.forEach(function(Addtasks){
    Addtasks.Bigpaths.forEach(function(Bigpaths){
        paths.push({name: Bigpaths.name});
    });
})
console.log(paths);
```

Comment: But how to access the items?

Comment: Here I looked upon it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794398/read-a-value-from-json-array-in-node-js How to access the Tag array ?

Comment: i am not getting you, which tag array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794398/read-a-value-from-json-array-in-node-js  Check this link. How to access the Tags array inside Images array ?

Comment: ok now i am confuse with your original question, you need to prepare a query to get only items, then this is the query, second you have already data and want items loop through?

Comment: yes i am trying this with loop but it isnt working throwing an error: data.Addtasks[0]["Bigpaths"].forEach(element => {.... like shown here in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794398/read-a-value-from-json-array-in-node-js for  data.images[0]["State"] I was trying this for array Bigpaths in my code. Now you got it?

Comment: okay let me know one thing main document (data) variable is a object or an array?

Comment: data is an object. inside data 'Addtasks' is an array. Inside Addtasks; 'Bigpaths' is another array. I want to access all the elements for Bigpaths array and want to use it with forEach loop.